# How do I enumerate IIS websites using Powershell and find the app pool for each?

Tags: powershell, iis, wmi

I can search for websites using:

```
Get-WmiObject -Namespace "root\WebAdministration" -Class Site -Authentication PacketPrivacy -ComputerName $servers
```

And I can list the app pools using:

```
Get-WmiObject -computer $servers -Namespace root\MicrosoftIISv2 -Class IIsApplicationPoolSetting -Impersonation Impersonate -Authentication PacketPrivacy
```

How can I link these together to find which app pool is associated to which website? It's a Windows Server 2008 R2 server with IIS 7.5.

Comment: Look at the `WebAdministration` module. It's much easier to work with than WMI

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following:

```
[Void][Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.Web.Administration")
$sm = New-Object Microsoft.Web.Administration.ServerManager
foreach($site in $sm.Sites) {
    foreach ($app in $site.Applications) {
        [PSCustomObject]@{
            Application = $site.Name + $app.Path
            Pool = $app.ApplicationPoolName
        }
    }
}
```

The script above lists every site on the server and prints the root application pool name for each site.

Answer (score 29):

Use the webadministration module:

```
Import-Module WebAdministration

dir IIS:\Sites # Lists all sites
dir IIS:\AppPools # Lists all app pools and applications


# List all sites, applications and appPools

dir IIS:\Sites | ForEach-Object {

    # Web site name
    $_.Name

    # Site's app pool
    $_.applicationPool

    # Any web applications on the site + their app pools
    Get-WebApplication -Site $_.Name
}
```

Comment: The topic starter is asking for remote connection with variable $servers. Your solution does not seem to provide the remote connection option.

Answer (score 6):

Here's another option using [**`IISAdministration`**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/iisadministration/?view=windowsserver2022-ps) if you do not want to use the `IIS:\` path.

```
Import-Module IISAdministration

$site = Get-IISSite -Name 'my-site'
$appPool = Get-IISAppPool -Name $site.Applications[0].ApplicationPoolName
```