# Powershell command to export IIS websites and app pools of a remote server

Tags: powershell, iis, command-line, web, export

I have the command which exports websites of the current logged in server (*as below*). I need the command to export websites of a different server.

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd list site /config /xml > c:\websites.xml

Answer (score 3):

try with [Invoke-Command](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/reference/5.1/microsoft.powershell.core/invoke-command)

Note the syntax you have is for a dos command. The following should get you on track. Of course there is credentials you may have to pass in.

Remoting must be enabled on the remote servers Run `Enable-PSRemoting -Force` on each server.

```
Invoke-Command -Computer remoteserver -ScriptBlock { 
    & $Env:Windir\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe list site /config /xml
} | Out-File c:\websites.xml -Append
```

Note that the 'powershell' way of getting sites as powershell objects is shown here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25091831/1165140

Comment: Thank you, @avvi

I kind of figured it out later. I used the PSSession command to establish the connection to the remote server and executed the Invoke-Command as you have mentioned.

` Enter-PSSession $SourceServerName
    Invoke-Command -ComputerName $SourceServerName -FilePath $ExtractWebsiteScriptPath -ArgumentList $WebServerTemplateXML,$SourceServerName,$DestinationServerName
Exit-PSSession`

Comment: New to stackoverflow, so please don't mind the formatting